# Rearrange elements in the such that the sum of product adjacent elements is maximized

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization

Given a sequence that contains n ( 1 <= n <= 10 ^ 5 ) integers, represented by [a1, a2, a3, ...., an] (0 <= ai <= 10 ^ 5 ), you have  to reorder the sequence to maximize the formula  $\Sigma_{1}^{n-1}$  a<sub>i</sub> * a<sub>i+1</sub>.

That is, the goal is to reorder the array so the sum of products of adjacent pairs of integers is maximized.

Input

```
n = 10
arr = [1, 2, 1, 5, 4, 2, 1, 1, 8, 9]
```

Output

```
best sum of products of adjacent pairs is 173
from arr = [1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 5, 2, 1]
```

Input

```
n = 3
arr = [5, 2, 0]
```

Output

```
best sum of products of adjacent pairs is 10
from arr = [0, 2, 5]
```

I am not getting any idea.

Comment: The first example shows what you need to do. The second example is a red herring, since any arrangement that doesn't have the 0 in the middle will work. A different answer to the second example is `2 5 0`. That arrangement follows the pattern of the answer to the first example.

Answer (score 2):

Sort.

Put all values with even indices adjacent; ditto for odd. Reverse the numbers from even indices and stitch them after the odd.

E.g.

```
1 2 1 5 4 2 1 1 8 9
sort: 1 1 1 1 2 2 4 5 8 9
even indices: 1 1 2 4 8
odd indices: 1 1 2 5 9
flip even & stitch together with the largest facing:
  1 1 2 5 9 8 4 2 1 1
This is slightly different from your result, but has the same output of 173.
```

Ruby code:

```
def f(arr)
  arr.sort!
  even = []
  odd = []
  arr.each_with_index do |val, i|
    if i%2 == 0
      even.append val
    else
      odd.append val
    end
  end
  final_arr = odd + even.reverse
  output = 0
  0.upto(final_arr.length - 2) do |i|
    output += final_arr[i] * final_arr[i+1]
  end
  puts final_arr.to_s
  return output
end
```

Results

```
> f([1, 2, 1, 5, 4, 2, 1, 1, 8, 9])

[1, 1, 2, 5, 9, 8, 4, 2, 1, 1]
=> 173
```

Comment: This is equivalent to building your list by repeatedly taking the largest unpicked element, and placing it next to the largest element in the list of placed elements. The goal is to have big numbers adjacent.